# zsh: permission denied when trying to use flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working with flutter for a week now and it runs okay, however I can't use commands such as `flutter doctor` or `flutter upgrade` on my terminal nor Android studio. Whenever I try to run a flutter command I get

`zsh: permission denied: /Users/name/flutter/bin`.

I tried adding the source to nano ~/.zshrc  and export PATH, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I faced this issue when setting up Flutter on my new mac, even after setting the PATH correctly. Turns out i installed the wrong SDK (Window). So make sure to install the correct Flutter SDK on your respective OS.

**For MacOS :**
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

**For Window :**
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

**For Linux :**
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux

**For ChromeOS :**
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/chromeos

Comment: Thanks Sunn downloading the right version helped me

Comment: lol creepy crap hahahahha

Comment: I made this mistake twice lol.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've installed the correct SDK for your machine. For me I had installed Flutter's Windows SDK on my Mac machine.

For macOS : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

For Window: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows

Answer (score 4):

Run below command in the terminal, it worked for me

```
export PATH="/<full-path-of-flutter-folder>/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I think it's even better to add this line to **/.zshrc**

Answer (score 3):

If you added the path and sure that you have downloaded the correct os files and still get the error:

- Go to flutter folder
- Empty folder
- Open terminal and go to the flutter folder
- git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thank you! It was driving me crazy.

Comment: I had macos version installed and I had this issue. so I tried your solution and I still have this issue. it's been a near a year that I'm trying to add flutter to path since I bought new macbook. wtf

Answer (score -3):

add the `sudo` prefix to your command. I guess you are not the admin.

eg: `sudo flutter doctor`

Comment: Then it means the path you added to the ~/.zshrc is wrong.

Comment: I am the admin btw. And i tried changing it with nano again, but when I ran `source`, it says permission denied again. Will I have any issues if I delete reinstall flutter?

Comment: No. You can try reinstalling it. Give it a try, Also refer this while you are setting up flutter https://medium.com/@alexandrosbaramilis/setting-up-flutter-on-macos-catalina-d023df8845ae